# TextView disappears

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a textview that don't appears on the emulator/real device. Here is the CardView xml code, that I use to add cardviews to a recycler view.

(The one that don't appear is the last one on XML text, "há 10 minutos")

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/card_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sabia que:"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/md_keylines"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/md_keylines"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/md_keylines"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
            android:textSize="@dimen/article_titles"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/card_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/card_title"
            android:text="asdjksah asdhsa oidhs diosah saidh asoidhsd saoidsahd iaosd hsaid hasoih "
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/md_keylines"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/md_keylines"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/md_keylines"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/md_keylines"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
            android:textSize="@dimen/article_subheading" />

        <!--Isto é dentro da Text view acima -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/action_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/md_keylines"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/md_keylines"
            android:layout_below="@+id/card_text"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorAccent"
            android:text="Saber mais" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/share_button"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/cards_button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/cards_button_height"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/md_keylines"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/card_text"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/md_keylines"
            android:tint="@color/button_grey" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="há 10 minutos"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
             />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**On android studio:**

[image]

**On emulator(the same issue as the real device**

[image]

The text is different because I use a XMLParser for the phrases.

Comment: You mean the text: `há 10 minutos`??

Comment: Yes, that's why I wrote the last one in the xml text, and why I put the xml text first. But I will edit !

Comment: comment `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"`

Comment: @AntónioPaulo For test case add `android:paddingLeft="10dp"` textview and textcolor

Comment: I think add `android:layout_below="@id/textView2"` in `card_title` textview

Comment: Tried all of your suggestions and no one worked. I already cleaned/built the project

Comment: Try using the below code for your last textview,    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"             
    android:layout_below="@+id/ action_button"
            android:text="há 10 minutos"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
             />

Comment: Just a tip: for previewing tour `TextView` you can use `tools:text` instead of `android:text`. That way you will see how it looks in Android Studio's preview but it will have an empty text until you set it. If you forget to call `card_text.setText(someThing)` you won't want the user to see that ugly text ;) Take a look to the [Designtime Layout Attributes](http://tools.android.com/tips/layout-designtime-attributes) page

Comment: I just wrote that for you to see it. How do you see a TextView without text ? :)   I use a XMLParser to write the text.

Comment: Do you believe that the textview color was my problem all the time?

Answer (score 0):

You are using relativelayout that let his contents overlapping each others. You have to specify android:layout_below in your last TextView to specify position as the previous ones.